# mining block calculations on client side

Tags: node.js

I create simple blockchain with node.js and now I understand that because of running codes on server, all calculations such as mining a block are done on the server-side but I want to use client (miner) hardware power to do these calculations (like bitcoin) what have I do? I searched a lot on internet but I dont find somehing useful.
Problem is: This is the code for mining a block that I want to run on the miner's hardware while it is currently running on the server.

```
const { GENESIS_DATA, MINE_RATE } = require("./../config");
const {cryptoHash} = require("./../util");
const hexToBinary=require('hex-to-binary');


class Block {
  constructor({ timeStamp, hash, lastHash, data, difficulty, nonce }) {
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    this.hash = hash;
    this.lastHash = lastHash;
    this.data = data;
    this.difficulty = difficulty;
    this.nonce = nonce;
  }
  static genesisblock() {
    return new Block(GENESIS_DATA); //or: return new this(GENESIS_DATA);
  }
  static mineBlock({ lastBlock, data }) {
    let hash, timeStamp;
    let difficulty = lastBlock.difficulty;
    let nonce = 0;
    do {
      nonce = nonce + 1;
      timeStamp = Date.now();
      difficulty = Block.adjustdifficulty({
        originalblock: lastBlock,
        timeStamp: timeStamp,
      });
      hash = cryptoHash(Date.now(), lastBlock.hash, data, nonce, difficulty);
    } while (hexToBinary(hash).substring(0, difficulty) !== "0".repeat(difficulty));
    return new Block({
      timeStamp: Date.now(),
      lastHash: lastBlock.hash,
      data: data,
      difficulty: difficulty,
      nonce: nonce,
      hash: hash,
    });
  }
  static adjustdifficulty({ originalblock, timeStamp }) {
    const difficulty = originalblock.difficulty; // or const {difficulty}=originalblock.difficulty;
    if (difficulty < 1) return 1;
    if (timeStamp - originalblock.timeStamp > MINE_RATE) return difficulty - 1;
    return difficulty + 1;
  }
}
module.exports = Block;
```

Comment: This question is akin to "I want to set up a colony on mars and I searched a lot of internet but I didn't find any instructions". **This is not easy**. This will not be answered here.

Comment: If this question was easy, I wouldn't have spent so much time on it and I wouldn't have asked it here! I'm not here to get the full answer, I'm just looking for a clue so I can get to the answer. I also asked my question very clearly. Of course, the question of answering the Mars colonies is not raised among the programmers :) @tadman

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question that’s difficult to answer concisely and is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. Instead of leaving us to speculate on what you might need, give us something to build so we can focus help in those areas where it’s most needed.

Comment: I edited my question. My project is a cryptocurrency (website) with Node.js backend and React frontend .This is the code for mining a block that I want to run on the miner's hardware while it is currently running on the server. Tell me if you need more information. Thank you @tadman

Comment: A web site can't access hardware like that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

just create an app and then your client will download it and send you the Data. all calculations will do on client hardware